# i want to search for a string in a file using perl

Tags: perl

i want to search for a string in file using perl code

i want to search "unix" string from sample input file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "sample";
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   chomp $line;
   my @strings = $line = ~ /unix/g;
   foreach my $s (@strings) {
     print "'$s'";
   }
}
```

i am getting like this

Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at strings.pl line 8,  line 1.
'18446744073709551615'

Comment: use `$line =~ /unix/g;` not  `$line = ~ /unix/g;` You have a space between `=` and `~` where you shouldn't

Comment: `=~` is a single operator, don't put a space in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

As people have already mentioned in comments, you have a small typo. The binding operator, `=~`, cannot have a space between its two characters.

You might expect that adding that unwanted space would generate a syntax error. But, unfortunately, both `=` and `~` are used as operators so instead of a syntax error, you get a statement that does something completely different to what you expect.